# Consultas demasiado lentas en MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo una aplicación desarrollada en java para el control de un inventario, en la base de datos guardo los siguientes datos:

```
codigo INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nombre VARCHAR(50),
imagen LONGBLOB,
stock INT,
ruta VARCHAR(150),
constraint pkproductos Primary Key(codigo)
```

En la tabla **guardo la imagen del producto**, pero al momento de hacer la consulta para ver todos los productos registrados tarda demasiado, y quería ver si hay alguna forma de hacer las consultas mas rápidas,en total **tengo 122 productos registrados cada uno con su imagen**.

**Explain de consulta**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Utilizas algún ORM? generalmente cuando manejas una cantidad de registros alta vuelven lenta la ejecución. También te recomendaría intentar utilizar una columna BLOB en lugar de una LONGBLOB.

Comment: ¿cuánto es demasiado? ¿a dónde _traes_ los datos, hablando en términos de latencia de redes, ancho de banda y temas por el estilo, obviamente? ¿cuánto pesa cada imagen que has almacenado con tus artículos? Pregunto esto porque 122 filas no son muchas.

Answer (score 1):

Yo te recomiendo que no guardes la imagen en la base de datos, básicamente porque es un dato que puede ser muy pesado, además que esta práctica se hacía hace 10 años o más.

La solución que se usa para estos casos es guardar la imagen en una carpeta donde puedas tenerla visible desde la web donde la quieres mostrar y guardar el nombre de a imagen en el campo que ahora será un **`varchar`**, así el campo será mucho mas pequeño y práctico.

Luego donde tengas que mostrarlo basta con poner la url de la imagen que guardaste y ya lo tienes.

Comment: Ya modifique el codigo y la bd, ahora ya no guardo las imagenes en la base de datos, solo guardo la ruta y con esa ruta las mando a llamar, pero igual sigue tardando

Comment: has eliminado la columna y creado un varchar no? entonces haz un explain de la consulta y ponla en la pregunta a ver si el problema es ese.

Comment: ya aplique el explain

Comment: Me parece muy raro que demore tanto, cuando haces la consulta en la consola de mysql, cuanto te dice que se demora? puedes agregar un screen de ese resultado por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta no seleccionar la imagen en la instruccion SELECT que utilizas.

```
SELECT codigo, nombre, stock, ruta FROM TABLA
```

**¿Es obligatorio el almacenamiento de las imágenes en la base de datos?**

Si tienes que traer las imágenes en las consultas por lo menos a la hora de registrar las imágenes de los productos procura que dichas imágenes tengan un tamaño límite y las mismas sean tratadas con programas de edición de imágenes para reducir su tamaño.

Las imágenes suponen un mayor peso si están almacenadas en la base de datos porque las imágenes son archivos binarios de considerable volumen y peor aún si están guardadas sin tratar.

Imagínate una imagen 1 MB almacenada en la base de datos, se ve poco, ¿verdad?. Ahora imagina 122 MB siendo obtenidos en una consulta solamente en imágenes tendrías ese peso.

**¿Qué puedo hacer?**

Como comenté anteriormente intenta que las imágenes sean reducidas de tamaño antes de ingresar a la base de datos.

¿Cuál sería un tamaño adecuado?

Depende de lo que necesites, puedes tener dos casos posibles:

- **Calidad contra Rapidez:** si necesitas buena calidad en la imagen intenta reducir su tamaño sin perder mucha calidad.
- **Rapidez contra Calidad*(Opción ideal)*:** si puedes sacrificar calidad de las imágenes para obtener menor peso mejores resultados en tus consultas.

**Lo ideal**

Lo ideal sería tener un servicio web que te permita obtener las imágenes a través de una petición **HTTP** y guardar en el base de datos la ruta de acceso a dicha imagen. Las consultas serían muchísimo más rápidas, sin embargo tendrías que obtener las imágenes luego de obtener los artículos, serían dos pasos en vez de uno.

Comment: No seleccionar la columna de la imagen no sirve de nada: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883705/mysql-select-is-very-slow-because-longblob

Acá hay otra solución pero te aseguro que hacerlo así no llevará a ningún lado.

Comment: Tienes razón @sergiosusa pero me vi envuelto una vez en esta situación en mi trabajo. Pero por eso llegué a la conclusión de que las imagenes debían tener un peso razonable a la hora de guardarlas en la bd.

Comment: Y lo que dices podría ser una solución temporal, pero el problema es que al final llegas al mismo punto.

Comment: Exacto, al final de cuentas la cantidad de productos afectará al rendimiento de las consultas futuras.

Comment: por ejemplo, ahora ya no guardo las imagenes en la base de datos, solo guardo la ruta y con esa ruta las mando a llamar, pero igual sigue tardando

Comment: mi mejor *recomendación* es que investigues sobre el comando `EXPLAIN` y al momento de ejecutarlo el resultado que te devuelva anexalo a tu pregunta editándola pues de ese modo alguien mas se puede dar una idea de que es lo que ocurre @LuisDanielInterianoYañez

Answer (score 0):

Haz otra tabla por ejemplo producto_imagen, donde guardes solo las imágenes con el id codigo de la tabla producto, algo así mira:

[image: ER Propuesto]

Así podrás consultar en el uso normal del sistema la información de forma rápida, y cuando requieras la imagen del producto vas y la consulta en la otra otra tabla,  de esta manera podrás evitar que el motor tenga que escanear un campo BLOB a nivel disco cuando solo consultas el nombre del producto por ejemplo.

Saludos!

Comment: Una cosa es no consulta el campo y otra el proceso en el que el Motor escanea el disco para encontrar la información del campo en la fila correspondiente, es ahí cuando en la búsqueda de los registros, el motor tenga que escanear algún binario en el cual solo tendrá que ver que ahí esta aunque no es el campo que requiere. Por eso es que si separa la meta-data de la imagen podrá optimizar el proceso.